# how to use csv data to train a hugging face model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers

I want to fine-tune a pre-trained DistilBERT (transformer model based on the BERT architecture) model available Hugging Face. I did some data cleaning up/pre-processing step to generate a csv data and uploaded to an s3 bucket.

based on the example provided here (https://github.com/aws-samples/finetune-deploy-bert-with-amazon-sagemaker-for-hugging-face) , the code below is a train.py file .

I have a couple of csv file that i want to use for training and testing. in the code below, it looks like , it is loading data as below, how can i change this to be able to read and use csv, given csv is an s3 location.

```
train_dataset = load_from_disk(args.training_dir)
```

```
"""
Training script for Hugging Face SageMaker Estimator
"""
import logging
import sys
import argparse
import os
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments
from datasets import load_from_disk
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_recall_fscore_support

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # hyperparameters sent by the client are passed as command-line arguments to   the script.
    parser.add_argument("--epochs", type=int, default=3)
    parser.add_argument("--train_batch_size", type=int, default=32)
    parser.add_argument("--eval_batch_size", type=int, default=64)
    parser.add_argument("--warmup_steps", type=int, default=500)
    parser.add_argument("--model_name", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--tokenizer_name", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--learning_rate", type=str, default=5e-5)

    # Data, model, and output directories
    parser.add_argument("--output-data-dir", type=str, default=os.environ["SM_OUTPUT_DATA_DIR"])
    parser.add_argument("--model-dir", type=str, default=os.environ["SM_MODEL_DIR"])
    parser.add_argument("--n_gpus", type=str, default=os.environ["SM_NUM_GPUS"])
    parser.add_argument("--training_dir", type=str, default=os.environ["SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN"])
    parser.add_argument("--test_dir", type=str, default=os.environ["SM_CHANNEL_TEST"])

    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

    # load datasets
    train_dataset = load_from_disk(args.training_dir)
    test_dataset = load_from_disk(args.test_dir)

    # download model and tokenizer from model hub
    model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(args.model_name)
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(args.tokenizer_name)

    # define training args
    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=args.model_dir,
        num_train_epochs=args.epochs,
        per_device_train_batch_size=args.train_batch_size,
        per_device_eval_batch_size=args.eval_batch_size,
        warmup_steps=args.warmup_steps,
        evaluation_strategy="epoch",
        logging_dir=f"{args.output_data_dir}/logs",
        learning_rate=float(args.learning_rate),
    )

    # create Trainer instance
    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=test_dataset,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
    )

    # train model
    trainer.train()
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass S3 remote url to the function `load_from_disk`.

The argument is dataset_path described below.

> dataset_path (str) — Path (e.g. "dataset/train") or remote URI (e.g. "s3//my-bucket/dataset/train") of the dataset directory where the dataset will be loaded from.
> Reference - https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.8.0/en/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset.load_from_disk

```
from datasets import load_from_disk
# load encoded_dataset from cloud storage

dataset = load_from_disk("s3://a-public-datasets/imdb/train", storage_options=storage_options)  

print(len(dataset))
25000
```

In order to pass the S3 session details, you can look at the documentation below.
https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/filesystems#amazon-s3

```
storage_options = {"anon": True}  # for anonymous connection
# or use your credentials

storage_options = {"key": aws_access_key_id, "secret": aws_secret_access_key}  # for private buckets
# or use a botocore session

import botocore

s3_session = botocore.session.Session(profile="my_profile_name")

storage_options = {"session": s3_session}
```